# Disable silent types conversions in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to disable silent types conversions in numpy?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty(10, int)
a[2] = 4     # OK
a[3] = 4.9   # Will silently convert to 4, but I would prefer a TypeError
a[4] = 4j    # TypeError: can't convert complex to long
```

Can `numpy.ndarray` objects be configured to return a `TypeError` when assigning any value which is not `isinstance()` of the ndarray type?
If not, would the best alternative be to subclass `numpy.ndarray` (and override `__setattr__` or `__setitem__`)?

Comment: see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6971

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `numpy` doesn't offer this feature in array creation, you can set if casting is allowed only when you are converting an array (check the documentation for [`numpy.ndarray.astype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)).

You could use that feature, or subclass `numpy.ndarray`, but also consider using the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) module offered by python itself to create a typed array:

```
from array import array

a = array('i', [0] * 10)
a[2] = 4                   # OK
a[3] = 4.9                 # TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.

```
#Python 2.7.3
>>> def test(value):
...     if '.' in str(value):
...         return str(value)
...     else:
...         return value
... 
>>> a[3]=test(4.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '4.0'
```

Comment: It would be better to use an explicit mathematical check than converting to string, for example check for `int(value) == value`