# avoid numpy type coercion gotcha?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

This code gives a horrifying result (This is in Python 3.5, NumPy 1.10.):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,1])
a[1] = 2.5

print(a) -----> [0 2 1]
```

(When you try to put a float in an integer numpy array, it's rounded down with no warning!)

My question is: Is there any numpy setting and/or programming technique to *reliably* avoid this gotcha? Of course I know that I can use `a = np.array(..., dtype=float)` or `a = np.array([0., 0., 1.])` or whatever every time I declare an array, but I'm looking for something more reliable than that - I can be forgetful after all. For example, is there a switch in numpy that universally turns on warnings for sketchy type coercions? Or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the type of array elements is a property of the array itself, so that if you try to assign an element of another type to an array, it will be silently converted (if possible):

```
>>> T = a.copy()
>>> T[2] = -1.5
>>> T
array([ 0,  0,  -1])
>>> T[2] = -0.5j
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to int; use int(abs(z))
```

Note that the conversion that happens is a **default** conversion; in the case of float to int conversion, it's truncation. If you wanted something different, say taking the floor, you would have to arrange that yourself (for example with np.floor()). In the case of converting complex values to integers, there's no resonable default way to do it, so numpy raises an exception and leaves the array unchanged.
it means no way for this.

for more information see here:
https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

This was partly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471180/disable-silent-conversions-in-numpy). It does not seem possible to do this in numpy with a setting or flag.

If you don't need the more advanced numpy features, the python array type is a better behaved alternative (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25472082/5360405)).

The answer I linked to suggests subclassing np.ndarray. That would be a non-trivial task, to say the least.

The easiest way I can see is:

```
a = np.array([0,0,1])
a[1] = 2.5
assert a[1] == 2.5
```